# Win 95 VirtualBox guest does not see USB

Tags: windows, usb, virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox 6.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. I have two virtual machines set up: Win 95 and Win 10.  My windows 10 virtual machine is able to read the USBs I have connected to my host.  However, Win 95 does not seem to see/read them.  When I go to My Computer the USB drives are not there.

In my Win 95 Virtual Box USB settings I have USB Controller enabled and my USB device is listed as available in the filters.  NOTE: My USB is 1GB in size.  Could that be an issue with Win 95? (Win 95 can't handle a size that big?) Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how is this a linux question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Win95 and Win95a (OSR1 Service Pack 1) – no USB support.
- Win95b (OSR 2/2.1) and Win95c (OSR 2.5) had limited USB (1.0) support if `USBSUPP.EXE` was installed:

  - [Microsoft KB Archive/253756](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/253756)
  - [Q253756: Availability of Universal Serial Bus Support in Windows 95](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/253/Q253756/)
- There was an update (`USBSUPP2.EXE`) for OSR2.1 and OSR2.5 which claimed to have fixed some bugs of the previous version:

  - [Microsoft KB Archive/181661](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/181661)
  - [Q181661: Files Included with the USB Supplement in OSR2.1 and OSR2.5](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/181/Q181661/)

Note that supported devices were often keyboards, mice and printers in those days. It was not uncommon that you needed an extra driver for your device. Don't expect too much.

Comment: USB drives in particular need their own drivers, which often require Windows 98. On Windows 95, a network share would be easier to set up.